# Why does 'odbc show' command returns empty ODBC and DSN settings?

Tags: odbc, asterisk, sip, sip-server, vonage

I have my odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini as follows
odbcinst.ini

```
[asterisk-connector]
Description     = MySQL connection to 'asterisk' database
Driver          = MySQL
Database        = asterisk
Server          = localhost
UID =  asterisk
password = <mypassword>
Port            = 3306
Socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

And the odbcinst.ini will look like this:

```
~ $ more /etc/odbcinst.ini

[MySQL]
Description   = ODBC for MySQL
Driver      = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc.so
Setup      = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage   = 1
```

the res_odbc.conf file so it looks like the following:

```
[asterisk]
enabled => yes
dsn => asterisk-connector
UID => asterisk
password => <myPassword>
pooling => no
limit => 1
pre-connect => yes
```

And after running odbc show in asterisk CLI I see as follows.

```
ip*CLI> odbc show

ODBC DSN Settings
-----------------
```

Questions:
1) In the tutorial they see

```
*CLI> odbc show

ODBC DSN Settings
-----------------

  Name:   asterisk
  DSN:    asterisk-connector

    Last connection attempt: 1969-12-31 19:00:00
  Pooled: No
  Connected: Yes
```

1) Why am I not seeing the Name and DSN when I run `odbc show` ?
2) Also I get this

```
[Jul 16 18:38:25] NOTICE[10970]: chan_sip.c:29427 sip_poke_noanswer: Peer 'nexmo' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 81
[Jul 16 18:38:36] WARNING[11288]: db.c:285 db_execute_sql: Error executing SQL: database is locked
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likly you have error somewhere.

First can be recommended check files in odbcinst.ini  are present and valid.

If they are, do following:

```
asterisk -rvvvvv
module unload res_config_odbc.so
module load res_config_odbc.so
```

You will see where is error in your config.